# Ejecutar funciones de un objeto leyendo las propiedades desde un string

Tags: javascript

Tengo hecha una función que lee las propiedades de un objeto o un array desde un string, es decir que hace lo siguiente:

```js
renderProp({
    a:{
       key:"val"
    }
}, "a.key"); // "val"

renderProp([
  [
    "a",
    {
      b() {
        return "c";
      }
    }
  ]
], "[0][1].b"); // fn b()
```

La función la tengo hecha con un ciclo `forEach`, sin ningún tipo de `eval()`, y devuelve la propiedad que se le indique.

El problema viene cuando intento llamar a una función dentro del objeto o array

```js
function renderProp(e, r) {
    r.match(/\[[\s\S]*?\]/) && r.match(/\[[\s\S]*?\]/g).forEach(e => {
        r = r.replace(e, "." + e.replace(/\"|\[|\]|\'|\`/g, ""))
    });
    const c = (r = r.replace(/^\./, "")).split(".");
    let t = e;
    return c.length > 0 && c.forEach(e => {
        t = t[e]
    }), t
}

console.log(renderProp([
  [
    "a",
    {
      b(a1) {
        return a1;
      }
    }
  ]
], "[0][1].b('d')"));; // undefined, debería ser "d"

console.log(renderProp([
  [
    "a",
    {
      b(a1) {
        return a1;
      }
    }
  ]
], "[0][1].b"));; // fn b()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo debes analizar si hay paréntesis para tratar de identificar si se trata de una función o no; pero te van a quedar algunas tareas por resolver:

- Seguramente se puede mejorar si se usan expresiones regulares para saber si hay que ejecutar una función y extraer los parámetros (si los hay)
- Analizar los parámetros enviados a la función para obtener valores reales, sin comillas adicionales

```js
function renderProp(e, r) {
    r.match(/\[[\s\S]*?\]/) && r.match(/\[[\s\S]*?\]/g).forEach(e => {
        r = r.replace(e, "." + e.replace(/\"|\[|\]|\'|\`/g, ""))
    });
    const c = (r = r.replace(/^\./, "")).split(".");
    let t = e;
    return c.length > 0 && c.forEach(e => {
        // Buscar paréntesis
        if(e.indexOf('(') >= 0) {
            // Extraer el nombre
            let fn = t[e.substring(0, e.indexOf('('))];
            if(typeof fn == 'function') {
                // Extraer parámetros (lo que está entre paréntesis)
                let params = e.substring(e.indexOf('(') + 1, e.length - 1);
                // Ejecutar y asignar resultado
                t = fn(...(params.split(',')));
            } else {
                // ¿Deberías lanzar excepción?
                // ¿O solo devolver como cadena?
                t = t[e];
            }
        } else {
            // Valor normal
            t = t[e];
        }
    }), t
}

let conFuncion = [
  [
    "a",
    {
      b(a1, a2) {
        return a1 + ' - ' + a2;
      }
    }
  ]
];

console.log(renderProp(conFuncion, "[0][1].b('d', 'r')")); // Probando con 2 parámetros
console.log(conFuncion[0][1].b('d', 'r')); // Hay diferencia

console.log(renderProp([
  [
    "a",
    {
      b(a1) {
        return a1;
      }
    }
  ]
], "[0][1].b"));; // fn b()
```